# Measures equal on generating set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R},B^1,\mu )$ be a measure space, $B^1$ the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra.

We know that it has generating set $$G=\{(-\infty,x]\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

Given two other measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ on $B^1$ for which we have $\mu=\mu_1 + \mu_2$ on $G$. 
Is it true that $\mu=\mu_1 + \mu_2$ holds on $B^1$?

Comment: It is by assumption, see first phrase in my question. I just want to know if $\mu=\mu_1 +\mu_2$ on $G$ whether it is true on $B^1$ as well. I am sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false in general. Let $\mu=\mu_1=\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure, and $\mu_2=\delta_0$ the Dirac measure defined by

$$
\delta_0(A):=\begin{cases}
\infty ,&0\in A\\
0,&\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\mu':=\mu_1+\mu_2$ and $\mu$ are well-defined as measures in $B^1$ and trivially agrees in $G$, but $\mu'(\{0\})=\infty$ and $\mu(\{0\})=0$.